# Emulating 1:1 aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-emulator, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to create an android emulator that mimics an AW 414.Go smart watch (Android 4.2.2 API 17). However, I can't seem to make the aspect-ratio of the aspect ratio 1:1.

I create the device with a resolution of 240x240px, but the aspect ratio of the OS is not 1:1 (see screenshot). Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: wrong aspect ratio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the soft-buttons are at the side of the display, but dont show because of the small display size. Full screen apps work well.